# React Native Expo Building Javascript Bundle stuck at 99

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

I'm running my react-native app using expo on my mobile.

However, when I start the packager and connect to expo app on my mobile, it's stuck at 99% for building javascript bundle process.

There has been no code change to cause this.

I have tried re-installing my node modules and restarting my packager after cleaning cache.

What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind sharing a screenshot? Did you try pressing i to start the iOS simulator (if you're using iOS) Personally, I use the Expo XDE to start my expo projects. As a last resort, you can always clone your project and start from there

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Turned out that i had to press enter in my console screen so it continued exporting to the expo app

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```